# fedora-20 Realtek Wifi Driver slow/errors/drops connection

Tags: performance, wifi, fedora

I have a new HP Pavilion running Fedora 20.  Wired internet is full speed, but there are several problems with my WiFi connection.

- When running best, the speed is a fraction of wired speed.
- The connection frequently cuts out completely.
- When loading a webpage, errors are thrown
- I would like to run 5G connection, but it does not look like it's available

Below I have listed the WiFi driver specs and an error log. Any help is greatly appreciated.

WiFi Driver Specs:

`lspci`

> 08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Error Log:

`journalctl -lf`

> Aug 19 19:13:03 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[2072]: [3025:3325:0819/191303:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
>
> Aug 19 19:19:24 localhost.localdomain kernel: perf interrupt took too long (2528 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
>
> [3025:3132:0819/192237:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
> Aug 19 19:22:37 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[2072]: [3025:3132:0819/192237:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1108801).

The only way round it at the moment is to download and compile the new version of the Realtek driver:

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

The last three commands can be run either with `sudo` as above, or else by running `su` after the first three, and then typing in the root password to become root.

(You'll need to experiment to see what dependencies you need installed to build the driver.)

Comment: Thanks! The wifi speed is now chugging along at about 1/4 of wired speed. Is bugzilla a good place to address issues like these initially?

Comment: Well, RedHat Bugzilla is where Fedora *bugs* get reported, so if you've got a problem that you suspect is a bug, it's the right place to search to see if it's been previously reported, and the right place to report it yourself if not. So it was the right place to go for this issue. But it isn't the right place for general help with Fedora.

Comment: I was trying to run using `make -j` and my computer crashed every time. Just a simple `make` (as it is in your post) worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

The very low wifi speed compared to wired is entirely normal for wifi, particularly under less than ideal circumstances.  Suggest you install wavemon and watch how the signal, signal to noise, retries, etc. slow wifi down.  Using wifi can slow you're whole network down by keeping the router busy resending bad packets.  it's not unusual for half the packets to have to be sent repeatedly (sometimes several times).  Wifi is convenient for some things, but will fundamentally always be slower than a wired connection.  This situation has been severely aggravated by the increasing use of wifi, and worse still channel bonding to increase speed which basically can try to tie up all the wifi channels, and then there are those fools who think more power is the answer but that only increases the interference from the high powered transmitter (also illegal).  Sadly the attempts to make wifi better have actually created more problems, which the industry now realizes.  Also note that you're likely to have more problems on the 5ghz channels as the signal is higher frequency and more sensitive to it's enviroment.  Having said that if most of the people around you aren't using the higher band it may work very nicely, until everyone starts overloading those channels as well.